# CodeIgniter Installation on godaddy with best security purposes

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

On `godaddy` hosting `public_html` is given as a web root. I'm trying to install `CodeIgniter` on it so I'd like the whole framework to be outside of `webroot` (for security reasons). For this specific purpose, in the `public_html` directory I've created `.htaccess` with the following code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sub_webroot/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./sub_webroot/index.php?$1 [L]
```

Directory/file structure looks like this:

```
public_html
    .htaccess
    CodeIgniter (whole framework files except index.php)
    sub_webroot
        index.php (CI index.php)
        assets
             sample.png
```

The framework is loaded successfully and `index.php` is removed as well. The problem which I am facing is that I can't open `sample.png` via `example.com/assets/sample.png` and it is obvious it is happening because of the line `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./sub_webroot/index.php?$1 [L]`. I can't made up my mind how it would be possible to access the `assets` directory and keep the framework working successfully as it is working now. Any ideas how to change `.htaccess` that meets my needs ?

Comment: better idea, get a better host, godaddy is one of the worst

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how we solved this problem: adding a condition to ignore the rewrite if requesting from the assets folder. You can add/remove options to ignore as required - really you only need the assets option in your case.

```
#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|css|png|jpg|gif|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
```

Place this before your RewriteRule.

There's a pretty comprehensive Codeigniter .htaccess for troublesome hosts at: http://www.chrishjorth.com/blog/one-com-codeigniter-htaccess-rewrite-rules/, that's nicely commented:

```
# @author: Chris Hjorth, www.chrishjorth.com
# Make index.php the directory index page
DirectoryIndex index.php
#Protect the .htaccess files
<Files .htaccess>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</Files>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /subfolder/
    # START CodeIgniter ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # based on http://www.danielwmoore.com/extras/index.php?topic=7691.0 and http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/132758/
    # Redirect default controller to "/".
    # This is to prevent duplicated content. (/welcome/index =&gt; /)
    RewriteRule ^(welcome(/index)?)/?$ /subfolder/ [L,R=301]
    # Remove /index/ segment on the URL, again to prevent duplicate content.
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/index/? $1 [L,R=301]
    # Remove trailing slashes, also to remove duplicate content
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    # Remove multiple slashes in between, just to remove the possibility of fabricating crazy links.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//(.*)$
    RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]
    # Ignore certain files and folders in this rewrite
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|frameworks|uploads|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
    # [NC] = no case - case insensitive
    # [L] = Last rule, last rewrite for this set of conditions
    # [QSA] = Query String Append, should be used to prevent all redirects from going to your default controller, which happens on 
    # some server configurations.
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subfolder/index.php?$1 [NC,L,QSA]
    # END CodeIgniter --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
</IfModule>
# If Mod_rewrite is NOT installed go to index.php
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```